# pgfplots: Optional graph range arguments in a macro

Tags: macros, pgfplots, optional-arguments

I defined a macro that inserts a plot that I can re-use the same graph style in multiple places. Mine actually loads data from a file, but a similar MWE looks like:

```
\newcommand{\drawGraph}[1]{
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=#1]
        \addplot {x^2};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
}
\drawGraph{10}
```

In this example, the argument is the value of `xmax` (`\drawGraph{10}` draws up to x=10).

How can I make this argument **optional**, so that I can just call `\drawGraph` and pgfplots will set the xmax value automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using the standard way to use an optional argument (default value empty):

```
\newcommand{\drawGraph}[1][]{...}
%                       ^  ^----- empty default value
%                       |-------- one argument
```

This relies upon the fact that `pgfplots` treats `xmax=` as the key `xmax` having not been set at all. So the empty default value causes `pgfplots` to calculate the axis limit as usual, but a specified value overrides that calculation.

The only other change is to switch from mandatory argument delimiters `{}` to optional argument delimiters `[]` in your usage of the command. Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\newcommand{\drawGraph}[1][]{
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=#1]
        \addplot {x^2};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\drawGraph
\drawGraph[10]
\drawGraph[15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be worth saying this relies on the (presumably true:-) fact that `xmax=` is legal pgfplots key equivalent to not setting the key.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I'll add it. And yes, it is true. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that optional arguments could be empty, nor that an empty pgfplot argument is the same as not setting the key. Is that true for all pgfplots arguments?

Comment: @Felix, I'm not prepared to make a general statement about that... xD This is definitely not the way the key-value system is meant to be used, but this solution gives you the desired behavior with a minimal change to your existing setup.

Comment: Understood, I was curious about how this extends to other situations. Your solution fits my problem perfectly.